# Who pass Spring ModelMap as parameter to controller method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I searched stackoverflow, spring specification, and just google for a long time but still cannot find the answer.

For example,

-------------------Example Method #1------------------------

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")

public String handleLogin(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String name){
  model.addAttribute("name", name);
  return "login";
}
```

---

In above method,

1. Who calls this method and in what situation?
2. What did the caller do to the model before it calls this method?
3. Which scope is this ModelMap object in? is it in request scope?
4. What is the requirements of the signature of this type of method?
   Can I arbitrarily create a method like following:

------------------Example Method #2-------------------------

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")

public String handleLogin(String s1, ModelMap model_1, int i, ModelMap model_2 @RequestParam String name){
  model_1.addAttribute("name", name);
  model_2.addAttribute("company", "good");//what are the initial status of model_1 and model_2?
  return "login";
}
```

In this method, I put 2 ModelMap parameters and the positions of them are arbitrary. Can the spring framework call this method so the modelmap can be used to carry data to a view just like the regular case in Example Method #1?

Generally can anyone illustrate the details of the life cycle of ModelMap before it is passed into the method?

Comment: If you want to know what a `@RequestMapping` method can accept and return, *read the documentation*: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods

Answer (score 3):

Please find the answers the below:

(1) Who calls this method and in what situation?

> This controller method will be invoked by Spring Dispatcher Servlet (&
>   handler methods) when "/login" request comes to the server

(2) What did the caller do to the model before it calls this method?

> Spring Dispatcher Servlet provides this model object for use with UI
>   tools.

(3) Which scope is this ModelMap object in? is it in request scope?

> No, Modelmap object will be used internally by spring handler methods to add the user defined objects (to be presented in UI) into the http response.

(4) What is the requirements of the signature of this type of method? Can

Both model_1 and model_2 will refer to the same model object as one object will be maintained per each request. The controller method signatures are flexible, you can find more info below link:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods

For more details on Modelmap, please refer below:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/ModelMap.html

Also, refer the spring dispatcher servlet lifecycle below:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: Thanks..provided te current doc.

Comment: I don't believe `ModelMap` is request-scope, since request-scope *beans* are backed by `RequestAttributes`. `ModelMap` is a local variable on the call stack, and doesn't have a scope.

Comment: For #4 (requirements of the signature), see [22.3.3 Defining @RequestMapping handler methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-methods)

Comment: Andreas: I agree with you, thank you. Correcting the answer.

Comment: If the ModelMap is created in local method in dispatch-servlet class, then the reference the ModelMap holds will be lost when a new request invokes this method in dispatch-servlet(no matter if the reference refer to a Session-scope object or Request_Scope object, the ModelMap itself will be a brand new one). I feel so confused because the ModelMap still holds old reference in the following example:

Comment: `@Controller  

@SessionAttributes("name")  

public class LoginController {  

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)  

    public String handleUserLogin(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String name) {  

        model.addAttribute("name", name);  

        return "login";  

    }  

}`

Answer (score 1):

(I haven't got chance to read the documentations developer&Andreas suggested, but anyway the following comments should be valid by its own) If the ModelMap is created in local method in dispatch-servlet class, then the reference the ModelMap holds will be lost when a new request invokes this method in dispatch-servlet(no matter if the reference refer to a Session-scope object or Request_Scope object, the ModelMap itself will be a brand new one). I feel so confused because the ModelMap still holds old reference in the following example:

```
   @Controller        
    @SessionAttributes("name")       
    public class LoginController {       
        @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)       
        public String handleUserLogin(ModelMap model, @RequestParam String name) {       
            model.addAttribute("name", name);       
            return "login";       
        }       
    }
```

With the above code, the "name" attribute is saved in ModelMap, but as I mentioned above, the variable "model" will lost all its member attributes after exiting this call.

So looks it is a contradiction that the "name" attribute is

1. a session scope attribute
2. is saved in a local variable and this variable loses all its reference when local method exits